# Run Mysql queries simultaneously with nodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I have a Node.js/Express app that queries a MySQL db.

```
async.parallel([
   function(){ Mysql query 1 },
   function(){ Mysql query 2 }
```

], callback);

Using one MySQL connection, I think that I am not able to run the 2 queries simultaneously and I will be forced in MySQL Server side to wait query 1 before execute query 2.
But if have one connection for each query, that means that both of them cam be executed in the same.
Can someone tell me if this is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MySQL library handles creating and disposing of connections automatically this might be handled for you transparently, some libraries have a connection pool. If it's a single connection you must, by definition, wait.

[Sequelize supports this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/docs/usage/) and is probably a better way of accessing MySQL than banging against the low-level driver.